# Pass dictionary as a value to launchArguments for UI Tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, xctestcase

I am trying to pass a value represented as a dictionary for launchArguments in order to run UI Tests.

So, I have tried to convert the dictionary to a String format and pass it like that:

```
let dic = ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"]
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(dic)
    if let value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        launchArguments += [ "-launchKey", value ]
    }
} catch {
    print("Error encoding launchArguments: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

When the app starts, it doesn't add a dictionary to UserDefaults. It doesn't give any information as well. What might be a problem?

Answer (score -1):

launchArguments is array of string:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments

launchEnvironment is a dictionary:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500427-launchenvironment

you can access launchEnvironment key:
ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["yourKey"]